# When is StringIO used, as opposed to joining a list of strings?

Tags: python, stringio

Using StringIO as string buffer is slower than using list as buffer.

When is StringIO used?

```
from io import StringIO


def meth1(string):
    a = []
    for i in range(100):
        a.append(string)
    return ''.join(a)

def meth2(string):
    a = StringIO()
    for i in range(100):
        a.write(string)
    return a.getvalue()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    from timeit import Timer
    string = "This is test string"
    print(Timer("meth1(string)", "from __main__ import meth1, string").timeit())
    print(Timer("meth2(string)", "from __main__ import meth2, string").timeit())
```

Results:

```
16.7872819901
18.7160351276
```

Comment: Do you possibly mean "When" instead of "Where" above?

Comment: Try meth1 with list comprehension.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If you measure for speed, you should use `cStringIO`.

From the [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/stringio.html):

> The module cStringIO provides an
>   interface similar to that of the
>   StringIO module. Heavy use of
>   StringIO.StringIO objects can be made
>   more efficient by using the function
>   StringIO() from this module instead.

But the point of StringIO is to be a *file-like object*, for when something expects such and you don't want to use actual files.

**Edit:** I noticed you use `from io import StringIO`, so you are probably on Python >= 3 or at least 2.6. The separate StringIO and cStringIO are gone in Py3. Not sure what implementation they used to provide the io.StringIO. There is `io.BytesIO` too.

Comment: Try it with `cStringIO`. Results: List: 17, cString: 33.

Comment: io.StringIO is a C implementation, if that exists on your platform. If not it uses a Python implementation fallback. The reason it's slower is because he is doing something that he doesn't need StringIO for in the first place.

Comment: The module `cStringIO` has been [removed](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html#text-vs-data-instead-of-unicode-vs-8-bit) in Python 3.

Answer (score 35):

The main advantage of StringIO is that it can be used where a file was expected. So you can do for example (for Python 2):

```
import sys
import StringIO

out = StringIO.StringIO()
sys.stdout = out
print "hi, I'm going out"
sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__
print out.getvalue()
```

Comment: Can it be used with `with` in python 2 ? From what I see here no: http://bugs.python.org/issue1286

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D please see [http://bugs.python.org/issue1286#msg176512](http://bugs.python.org/issue1286#msg176512) which states that it will work from 2.5 up.  What more do you want, blood on it? :D

Comment: @MarkLawrence: no it won't - reread the comment you linked - you have to roll _your own_ context manager

Answer (score 18):

Well, I don't know if I would like to call that using it as a "buffer", you are just multiplying a string a 100 times, in two complicated ways. Here is an uncomplicated way:

```
def meth3(string):
    return string * 100
```

If we add that to your test:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

    from timeit import Timer
    string = "This is test string"
    # Make sure it all does the same:
    assert(meth1(string) == meth3(string))
    assert(meth2(string) == meth3(string))
    print(Timer("meth1(string)", "from __main__ import meth1, string").timeit())
    print(Timer("meth2(string)", "from __main__ import meth2, string").timeit())
    print(Timer("meth3(string)", "from __main__ import meth3, string").timeit())
```

It turns out to be way faster as a bonus:

```
21.0300650597
22.4869811535
0.811429977417
```

If you want to create a bunch of strings, and then join them, meth1() is the correct way. There is no point in writing it to StringIO, which is something completely different, namely a string with a file-like stream interface.

Answer (score -1):

Another approach based on Lennart Regebro approach.
This is faster than list method (meth1)

```
def meth4(string):
    a = StringIO(string * 100)
    contents = a.getvalue()
    a.close()
    return contents

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from timeit import Timer
    string = "This is test string"
    print(Timer("meth1(string)", "from __main__ import meth1, string").timeit())
    print(Timer("meth2(string)", "from __main__ import meth2, string").timeit())
    print(Timer("meth3(string)", "from __main__ import meth3, string").timeit())
    print(Timer("meth4(string)", "from __main__ import meth4, string").timeit())
```

Results (sec.):

> meth1 = 7.731315963647944
>
> meth2 = 9.609279402186985
>
> meth3 = 0.26534052061106195
>
> meth4 = 2.915035489152274

Comment: I don't think there could ever be any use for wrapping a string in `StringIO` just to immediately convert it back to a string again and discard the `StringIO` object, especially if you care about runtime.