# Read mail attachment & that use it for pyPdf2: PdfFileReader

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, pypdf

I'm just trying to read mail attachment (PDF file attached) in memory so that i can use that it for **pyPdf2**

Here is the basic code,

```
from pyPdf2 import PdfFileReader
.
.
for attachment in message.attachments:
   attachment_name = attachment[0].decode()
   attachment_content = attachment[1].decode()
```

Here i just wanted to know that how much pages (page count) attached pdf has using `attachment_content` & `attachment_name` variable,

For more info, There is a method in `pyPdf2`, using that we can get pages count.

```
pdf_instance = PdfFileReader(file(file_path, "rb")) #But i'm stuck here, how to specify here *file_path* & not able to use that *attachment_content* & *attachment_name* varible
pdf_instance.getNumPages()
```

Any body can help me out here to use `PdfFileReader`

Thanks.

Niks

Comment: you probably want to use a StringIO object to "fake" a file for PdfFileReader to use.

Comment: @PaulCollingwood: Could you please elaborate it through example? that would really help me to understand clearly.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like (untested):

```
import StringIO

output = StringIO.StringIO()
output.write(attachment[0].decode())

df_instance = PdfFileReader(file(output, "rb"))
```

[What is StringIO in python used for in reality?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7996479/what-is-stringio-in-python-used-for-in-reality)

http://effbot.org/librarybook/stringio.htm

Even if the above is not quite right, you should be able to make it work after reading a StringIO tutorial or two.

Comment: Do you want to give this a Python  3 update?